# A skunk that makes you sleep

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, biochemistry

I am trying to develop an herbivore/rodent which, for the lack of better naming, I have temporarily named "sleepy skunk".

The main feature of this animal is that, whenever it feels threatened or is attacked, it freezes, sprays a mixture of gas and droplets and then assumes a "ball posture", wrapping around itself. The mixture is produced either in its intestine or in a gland evolved for that purpose, located around the perineum.

The mixture is active by both inhalation and mucosae contact, and its effect on the target is that it induces a drowsy state or even loss of consciousness, depending on the concentration. The sleepy skunk avoid its effects by being able to sustain apnea and immobility for several minutes, enough for letting the gas knocking out the attacker and then leave the scene.

Is there a realistic chemical path for an animal, or its intestinal flora, to be able to synthetize a chemical with such features?

Comment: That would be an awful lot of gas if the effect is to happen in open air... Better consider a mist of liquid droplets, as actual skunks actually use. (The problem with a critter emitting a humongous amount of gas is that it obviously needs to be stored under high pressure, to account for the critter not having an enormous wolume; and biology doesn't mix well with high pressure containers.)

Comment: @AlexP, valid point, corrected

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_use_by_non-human_organisms

Comment: I can't help but think that an animal that could "defensively" put other animals to sleep would sooner or later transition into using this as a method of predation.

Comment: I imagine the skunk covers it's fluffy tail with chroloform and hang itself on a coat hanger...

Comment: @Jedediah not necessarily, there are frogs that will "piss" in your eyes if you grab them but they don't use that to catch prey.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw You're still potentially dangerous with your eyes irritated (or gouged out!).  If anything, you're even more likely to thrash, claw, and bite.  This is significantly the less the case if you're unconscious.  And if you're sufficiently anaesthetized that you're not going to fight back if something chews on you, you're effectively a free meal.

Comment: Why would it assume a ball position after? I would expect similar to skunks, squid,and other animals that it would spray and bail.. That is, not all targets will be affected equally, so better to go while the going is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an opiate (or [opioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opioid)) of some kind might fulfill your requirements.

In the real world, fentanyl dust is quite a dangerous thing and police and paramedics who come into contact with it at the scene of an incident are at some risk: [Protecting First Responders from Fentanyl](https://www.safetyandhealthmagazine.com/articles/18290-protecting-first-responders-from-fentanyl-exposure-niosh-releases-video). Some kind of fentanyl was used in the [Moscow theatre hostage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_theater_hostage_crisis). Note that opioid overdoses can cause death by respiratory depression!

Natural opiates obviously exist, and many kinds of opioids are synthesised internally in various colours and flavours of species for different purposes. Something quite as powerful as fentanyl might be a bit surprising, but not entirely impossible.

Note that if it were as dangerous as fentanyl and related chemicals are, it might be suitable for hunting with rather than merely defense.

Note also that an animal that farted heroin when stressed seems like something likely to be caught and farmed for recreational (and maybe even medicinal) purposes.

Comment: Dolphins seem to be doing that already with puffer fish (about your last sentence)

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica they do indeed,  and tetrodotoxin is a really startlingly nasty chemical to be messing with for fun. Goes to show how similar humans and dolphins are; stupid junkies of the world, unite!

Comment: The difficulty with opioids, tranquilizers, sedatives, etc. is that the response varies heavily depending on the individual (genetics, body mass, etc.) so that to reliably incapacitate its predators, it would have to deliver enough of the chemical to be fatal to the target probably more 2/3 the time (through central nervous system depression sufficient to cause respiratory failure as Starfish Prime said).  Anesthesiology is a medical specialization for a reason; it's hard to knock a person out without killing them.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan on the flip side though, someone who has had a generous enough dose of opiates is probably not feeling particularly violent or inclined to run away, so they might be considered to be incapacitated if not actually unconscious. Still, your comment seems like it would make for the basis of a useful answer; you should make one!#

Answer (score 3):

The skunk produces

## [Diethyl ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diethyl_ether)

> Diethyl ether, or simply ether, is an organic compound in the ether class with the formula (C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>5</sub>)<sub>2</sub>O, sometimes abbreviated as Et<sub>2</sub>O (see Pseudoelement symbols). It is a colorless, highly volatile, sweet-smelling ("Ethereal odour"), extremely flammable liquid. It is commonly used as a solvent in laboratories and as a starting fluid for some engines. **It was formerly used as a general anesthetic, until non-flammable drugs were developed, such as halothane**. It has been used as a recreational drug to cause intoxication. It is a structural isomer of butanol.

Looking at its structure we can see that it is relatively simple - four carbons and, unlike most other incapacitating agents, it has no fluorine. I believe there is no living being that produces it, but due to its simplicity it is quite believable that some bacteria could produce it in an alternative world.

Perhaps bacteria in the gut of the skunk produce this ether.

This ether is relatively safe - most hospitals in Brazil, specially the public ones, reek of it. It will give you an euphoric high if you smell it on a piece of fabric and is a popular recreational drug to this day (we have a funny name for it as a drug: "lol lol"). In order to knock someone out, though, you need a high concentration. Still, ether is safe in that it knocks you out before you can manage to OD yourself.

Notice that at due to the high, skunk sniffing in your world might be the equivalent to our real world toad licking.